# Remove scroll bar in my template

Tags: jquery, html, css, templates

I would like to remove the scrollbar in my template :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>


    <section class="main clearfix" style="display:inline;">
        <div class="work">
            <a href="inner.html">
                <img src="img/work1.jpg">

            </a>
        </div>


    </section><!-- end main -->

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I would like to display the page as it : 
[website](https://popcorntime-online.io/)

Comment: They use this https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll

Comment: @AndrewBone ;  that works very well (y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the overflow css property set to hidden for the area you dont want a scrollbar to show.

```
overflow:hidden;
```